# Real eigenvalues with complex eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can a real eigenvalue (of a matrix that has two real and two complex conjugate eigenvalues) correspond to a complex eigenvector?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, and you don't even need the complex eigenvalues. E.g., $[i , 0]$ is an eigenvector of the identity matrix.

Comment: @eyeballfrog though the identity matrix does not have necessarily complex eigenvectors

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Take, for instance, the matrix$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&-1\\0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$Its eigenvalues are $1$ (multiplicity two), $i$, and $-i$. And $(i,i,0,0)$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: Thank you, I had a similar doubt